# Allow Decimal value in number

Tags: jquery, decimal

I have form filed in some amount has to be enter. Amount is separated by commas and decimal is not allowed. I want to allow decimal in amount. Thanks in advance...

Here is my Code :

```
(function($, undefined) {

    "use strict";


    $(function() {

        var $form = $( ".number" );
        var $input = $form.find( ".no" );

        $input.on( "keyup", function( event ) {

            var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
            if ( selection !== '' ) {
                return;
            }


            if ( $.inArray( event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39] ) !== -1 ) {
                return;
            }


            var $this = $( this );


            var input = $this.val();

            var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
            input = input ? parseInt( input, 10 ) : 0;

            $this.val( function() {
                return ( input === 0 ) ? "" : input.toLocaleString( "en-US" );
            });

        });



    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Will I get any solution for this. can anyone help me out from this ???

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

var $form = $( ".number" );
var $input = $form.find( ".no" );

$input.on( "keyup", function( event ) {



    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    if ( selection !== '' ) {
        return;
    }


    if ( $.inArray( event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39] ) !== -1 ) {
        return;
    }


    var $this = $( this );


    var input = $this.val();

            input = input ? parseFloat( input) : 0;

            $this.val( function() {
                return ( input === 0 ) ? "" : input.toLocaleString( "en-US" );
            } );
} );



  });
   })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its not working. Now amount is not divided by commas after 100 or thousand. But Decimal is allowed

Comment: If comma is a decimal separator, than it cannot be used as a thousand dividing character